# Console skipping while resetting Nextcloud password via OCC Command in a Docker container

Tags: docker

Unfortunately I can't access my Nextcloud due to both my normal user and admin user being locked as their password expired. I've tried resetting the password via OCC, but I can't enter a new password. The console just skips ahead. I'd really appreciate if somebody could tell me what causes this or how to stop it.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text you could copy and paste. You are just making it harder for others to help you when they need to type text from your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the `docker exec` interactively.

```
docker exec -it -u 33 nextcloud ./occ ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking that it would work like that by default. I'll have to look more into docker and get some more experience with it.